# Linq. Filter objects from nested list inside of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have list of objects that looks like this:

```
teams: [
  {
    "teamName": "Bayern",
    "players":[
      {
        "name": "Neuer",
        "status": "available"
      },
      {
        "name": "Muller",
        "status": "unavailable"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pavard",
        "status": "unknown"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teamName": "Borrusia",
    "players":[
    {
        "name": "Haller",
        "status": "available"
      },
    {
        "name": "Modeste",
        "status": "unavailable"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So in short i have list of teams where you can find `teamName` attribute and list of `players` in that team. Every player has `status` property which is `Enum`.
Is it possible to filter the nested list `players` so i am left with only the players that have status `available`?

I want to get at the end object like this:

```
teams: [
  {
    "teamName": "Bayern",
    "players":[
      {
        "name": "Neuer",
        "status": "available"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teamName": "Borrusia",
    "players":[
    {
        "name": "Haller",
        "status": "available"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code, just use a method 'Where' and you will get only players availables:

```
var result = teams.Select(team => new 
{ 
  teamName = team.teamName,
  players = team.players.Where(player => player.status == "available")
});
```